# How to bind data from Static class to Xaml

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have a static class in which one property defines a resource manager. for eg.

```
public static class MyClass
{
public static MyResourceManager {get;set;}
}
```

I want to bind the key from the resource manager to XAML. I am using Silverlight 4 with MVVM pattern.

If I do something like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding LocalResource.Refresh}"/>
```

where LocalResource is defined in my view model like this:

```
public object LocalResource {
get
{
return MyClass.MyResourceManager;
}
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better approach. I have made the class static as the resource file is loaded dynamically. I am loading it in the bootsrapper and have to use this across all my modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about instanciating your resourcemanager just once for your application like this:

```
<Application xmlns:myNS="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly" ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <myNS:MyResourceManager x:Key="MyResources" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then you can use it just like a normal WPF resource:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyResources}, Path=Refresh}" />
```

Comment: It gives following compile time error : Error 12 Type 'MyClass' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.

Comment: Don't use MyClass use MyRessourceManager. MyResourceManager needs to have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Is this supposed to also work if you want the static parameter to change within the lifetime of the app ? If so, how do I refer to it in code so I can change it?